# magento2 rest API url, change API url

Tags: magento2, rest-api

```
<route url="/V1/api/orders/:id" method="GET">
        <service class="Lovat\Api\Api\OrdersRepositoryInterface"
                 method="get"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
```

i create an API, and everything works well, but i i would like to change url API
now URL looks like that `http://localhost/rest/all/V1/api/orders/2`

how can i edit url to `http://localhost/api/V1/orders/2`

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way will be to create a rewrite rule and let it do the job.
Refer to this lijnk for creating a rule in Apache - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html

If using Nginx then you can also search for it about how to rewrite the url.
This way you don't have to change much of the code.

Comment: how is it possible to implement this with code?

Comment: Your server is running on nginx or apache? Accordingly the answer will vary

Comment: I am writing a plugin that will install on Magento
and I need to solve this problem with code if possible